# Count movies with specific score, per actor

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have `movies` and `actors` tables. Movies have a rating from 0 to 10. Each actor belongs to a group (table `groups`). Movies and actors are linked through `movies_actors` table.

For analytics purposes, I need the number of movies with rating between 0 and 1 (the upper bound excluded, named `count0`), between 1 and 2 (`count1`), ..., for every actor in a specific group.

Example of expected result:

```
actor_id | count0 | count1 | count2 | count3 | count4 | count5 | count6 | count7 | count8 | count9 |
---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
       1 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
       3 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
```

**sqlfiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e86f/7/0)**

As you can see in the sqlfiddle, I achieved to get count0, count1, ... for a specific actor whose id is hardcoded into the query.

**How do I get this information for every actor in a specific group?**

*Note: I use Postgres 9.4.1 with Ruby on Rails 5.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by actor_id to get the desired results. You might want to join `groups` in as well if you want to filter by a column in there. ([sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46a06/4/0))

```
SELECT
    actor_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score >= 0 and score <= 1 THEN 1 END) count0,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 1 and score  <= 2 THEN 1 END) count1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 2 and score  <= 3 THEN 1 END) count2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 3 and score  <= 4 THEN 1 END) count3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 4 and score  <= 5 THEN 1 END) count4,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 5 and score  <= 6 THEN 1 END) count5,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 6 and score  <= 7 THEN 1 END) count6,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 7 and score  <= 8 THEN 1 END) count7,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 8 and score  <= 9 THEN 1 END) count8,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN score > 9 and score  <= 10 THEN 1 END) count9
FROM movies
 INNER JOIN movies_actors ON movies_actors.movie_id = movies.id 
 INNER JOIN actors ON movies_actors.actor_id = actors.id
WHERE actors.group_id = 1
GROUP BY actor_id
```